# Does France allow international to Schengen transfer from India?

Tags: transit, france, covid-19, air-france

I'm an Indian citizen, trying to make my way into Europe from India. I have a type D visa issued by a Schengen country, and was planning on travelling via Air France transiting through Paris. It looks like I would have to do my immigration at Paris.

Air France mentions [here](https://www.airfrance.in/IN/en/local/resainfovol/meilleuresoffres/travelrestrictions.htm) mentions that I would be eligible to travel. There is also the clause (From [here](https://airfrance.traveldoc.aero/)) which says that the travel restriction does not apply to

> 2. nationals of India with a valid visa issued by a Schengen Area member state, provided their destination is a European Union or a Schengen Area member state;

However, the travel certificate required from entering metropolitan France (From [here](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Certificate-of-international-travel)) does not mention transit to another Schengen country as a "compelling" reason.

Is there anyone who has transited through France recently? Would I be allowed to transit through France?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you fully vaccinated? Can you do your work remotely? If you can do your job online, I'd wait until you're able to get both shots before traveling due to how dangerous things are in India right now.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention when you're planning to do the trip - I was crossing borders a few times during the last months within the Schengen area.

I don't know the reason for you to choose to go to a different country first. Please be aware that at the moment it's not that easy to travel within Schengen area. For example: Crossing from France into Germany you will have to fill out an electronic registration first. This will get checked at the border. Currently, if you come from India the 'elektronische Einreiseanmeldung' reads: "**Please note: a ban on carriage with very few exemptions is currently in effect.**"

Similar rules apply for all Schengen countries as far as I'm aware. For your own safety, be absolutely sure you'll be able to enter your country of destination. Fines are huge when they catch you - in Germany it's around 30.000€ as it's considered causing deliberate harm to all of society.

The rules might change a lot if you plan to arrive in three months instead of right now.